# how do I use a linear regression model on a specific case not in the DB, and get the prediction WITH a confidence interval?

Tags: spss

I wish to use the prediction model for a specific case not in the DB, without adding a line in the DB.

1. How can I do an automated calculation of the prediction (I mean: put parameter values, and get the prediction (average and Interval)
2. How do I get an interval of confidence of the prediction?

I find no way in the menus.

Comment: [This](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apply-spss-linear-regression-results-predict-response-new-cases-0) is what IBM has to say about it - I guess the answer is you can't.